# How do I overclock my RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, overclocking

I just built a pretty awesome computer on a i2700k Sandy Bridge processor and am pretty happy with it thus far. By just changing the multiplier, I have things fairly stable at 4.6 GHz on air, moving to liquid cooling today.

I'm not entirely sure where voltage comes into play here. Theoretically, at what point with the CPU do I need to start manually adjusting voltages? Furthermore, what voltages do I need to change? As far as I know, changing the BLCK voltage changes the frequency of the North Bridge , which is then multiplied by the CPU multiplier to get the clock speed of the CPU. I've also heard that this changes the RAM frequency as well.

How do I over clock my RAM and how do I measure the frequency of it? I'm somewhat new to overclocking and am not sure on how/when to change voltages and frequencies. I have [32GB of Corsair Vengeance 1866](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820233390) RAM.

Comment: Often times motherboards have auto-voltage on by default, so by increasing the clock, it probably over-volted. I would get [CPU-Z](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpuid.com%2Fsoftwares%2Fcpu-z.html&ei=L-jEUOmqAuqfyQHqloCgBA&usg=AFQjCNHUYv8vWcydE5qW4K5BW4pYKMVVIQ) ASAP and verify that your voltages are not over the recommended specs, because that will dramatically shorten the life of your CPU.  RAM usually has it's own settings, but the BUS speed ties over from the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would contact [these people](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/contact.php) as they will surely provide expert advice, as this is their specialty.

They also have a [comprehensive forum](http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/) where you may find the answer.